# Lose focus and move on for div tag

Tags: jquery

In my website I have the following code in `angular`:

```
<div class="create-new-type">
    <a ng-repeat="type in availableTypes" href="/{{type.type_name | lowercase}}/" ng-bind="type.name"></a>
</div>
```

I have this `div` tag hidden and it appears when the user clicks on a menu. The div tag will appear from the left side of the window. Problem is when the user clicks on the `tab` button it still shows focus on these links that are hidden. How do I (in jQuery) tell it to skip all elements in this `div` for focus if it's not showing and then move on to the next element?

I read the below regarding this:

[How to allow keyboard tab focusing on div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10227038/how-to-allow-keyboard-tab-focusing-on-div)

[Navigate the UI using keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16859970/navigate-the-ui-using-keyboard)

Comment: use display:none hide the links instead of other things like opacity or height 0

Comment: for each link or just the `div` tag?

Comment: div tag seems to work

Comment: That worked. Ill accept an answer if u put it down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use display:none to hide the links instead of other things like opacity or height 0