# I want to navigate to an arrow icon in each of my slickgrid cell

Tags: jquery, slickgrid

I am having a following rows in my slickgrid :

```
<div class="slick-cell">
    <div title="First">
        <span class="menu-icon">
          <i class="icon-folder"></i>
        </span>
        <span class="text">First</span>
        <div>
             <span class="number">2</span>
             <span class="arrow" tabindex="1">
                 <i class="icon-arrow"></i>
             </span>
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I have icon-arrow in each cell as shown above and want to reach to this arrow icon with tab key press once the cell is active, means on first tab press the cell should be active and on pressing the tab again the arrow should get focused so that I can apply keypress enter event on it.

Comment: You want to *set focus on the arrow* when pressing tab.   `span` by default does not take focus when tabbing.  You can add `tabindex` attribute *or* you can use a different element: either `<a>` or `<button>` (depending on what you're planning to do with the arrow, probably `button`).

Comment: Here's a solution on how to add tabindex: [How to allow keyboard tab focusing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10227038/how-to-allow-keyboard-tab-focusing-on-div) *but* you'll have to tell us if it works with [tag:slickgrid]